# there is a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon but Apple doesn't allow submit

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

[image]

[image]

I dragged and dropped the image in 1024x1024px icon many times but still the app doesn't go through. Is there any way to include the image using a code ?

Comment: Did you confirm that the icon you're trying to provide is in fact 1024x1024px?

Comment: yes I did online

Comment: What do you mean "online"? If you look at the actual file you've provided, is it a 1024x1024px file?

Comment: Is the icon in fact a PNG, or do you have something like a JPG?

Comment: PNG and it's surely 024x1024px

Comment: Ensure that it does not contain an alpha channel.

Comment: Is there a website where I can upload App Icon you can think of ?